# Error in installing react-native-vector-icon

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I have installed react-native-vector-icon but it is showing me error please let me know if you have any solution[image]

Comment: did you link the package? and if you did, did you restart your metro bundler?

Comment: can you explain to me more? I have linked the packages but don't have an idea to restart metro bundler.

Comment: You run `start` that sets up the bundler. You would then `react-native run-android`. You need to restart the bundler. And follow the install setup steps vector icons provides

Answer (score 0):

You try:

- react-native link react-native-vector-icons
- and follow:
  https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android
- react-native start
- react-native run-android